# Check if user opened a static file in Express?

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm serving static files using :

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

I have an index.html, and a bunch of other files under `./static/`, which is displayed on `http://localhost:8080`.

Is there some way I can intercept the GET request and figure out when a user has opened the static file? I tried

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { console.log("Opened!") }
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: change "/" to "/static/:filename" and dont pass a parameter to express.static()

Comment: @zee , you want to save history , or only last opened time ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think it would be last opened time. Since I think static files are fetched using a GET request, I'd like to be notified every time any user tries to load a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Thank you @robertklep for a refactor of my solution which wraps the whole thing up nicely. Here's a much more concise solution that notifies you when any static file is served, and prints its URL:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const static = express.static('static');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // declare a handler for the "request end" event
    function staticReqNotifier() {
        console.log("static file was served", req.url);
    }

    // listen to that event in before the static middleware is invoked
    req.on("end", staticReqNotifier);

    // manually invoke the static middleware with this middleware's arguments
    // we define the static middleware's next function - if it's called, the 
    // resource requested is not static so detach the listener and forward the response
    static(req, res, (err) => {
        req.off("end", staticReqNotifier);
        next(err);
    });
});

// test endpoint so show non-static requests work fine
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("test");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Because any express request can be fulfiled by at most only one middleware, listening for a "request has ended" event *before* the static middleware and detaching it after we're sure the static middleware hasn't fulfiled the request is sufficient. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice idea. I'm wondering if you could wrap it inside of a single middleware that calls the static middleware manually, so the logger function has access to `req`: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/a84cfd344d69348d4bd699339f200c6e